# Django model design using ForeignKey and ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models

I'm stuck and need some fresh eyes on my model design. I can't seem to wrap my head around how best to design this.

Reqs:

- Each project can have several tiers of service active at once, with the others being set to off. None are mutually exclusive
- The tiers are the same for all projects.
- I need to keep track of what tiers are active on a particular project.
- <s>I need to be able to associate a charge date for the project with active tiers</s>. See below for charge date clarification.
- The project and tiers 'active' fields are not related.
- See edit for more thoughts on my reqs.

Here's the models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('project name', max_length=128)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='projects')
    # A project could have more than one instance
    instances = models.ManyToManyField(Instance, related_name='projects') 
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    active = models.BooleanField()

class Tier(models.Model):
    TIERS = (('TI1', 'tier1'),
            ('TI2', 'tier2'),
            ('TI3', 'tier3'),
            ('TI4', 'tier4'),
            ('TI5', 'tier5'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TIERS)
    active = models.BooleanField()

class TierHistory(models.Model):

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='tier_history') 
    tiers = models.ManyToManyField(Tier)
    charge_date = models.DateField(null=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

An edit to clear things up:

The problem I'm having is that given the current design, I don't feel like I'm keeping track of tiers and if they're active in the best way possible. That is the main goal in all of this; to know what tiers are active on a project, and conversely be able to see what projects have ever had active any particular tier.

Given my current design, I can't set tier 2 active on project 1 and inactive on project 2.

- A project can have multiple tiers active simultaneously.
- The charge date will be for each tier. I realized that I read my spec wrong.
- I need to be able to report, "project 1 has been using tier 1 for 3 months, tier 2 for 6 months and has never used tier 5"
- I need to be able to report, "project 1 and project 2 have tier 1 active now, project 1 had tier 4 active for 1 month, project 3 and is the only project currently using tier 5"

Comment: You said you were stuck - what problem is this design causing you? You referred to 'a' charge date for the project, but since `TierHistory` has a `ForeignKey` to `Project` you can have multiple `TierHistories` and `charge_dates` for each project - is that what you want?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, I made an edit to my initial question to clarify my questions and to specify that I need a charge date per tier for each tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the questions you want to ask, it sounds like you need to keep a complete history of all changes to the status of a given tier. There are many ways to do that, here's a simple one. The basic idea is that every time you change the state of a tier you create a new `TierState`.

(Note that this is not fully normalized, since `current` is implicit in `change_time`. It makes lookups easier and state changes slightly harder.)

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # as before

class TierState(models.Model):
    TIERS = (('TI1', 'tier1'),
             ('TI2', 'tier2'),
             ('TI3', 'tier3'),
             ('TI4', 'tier4'),
             ('TI5', 'tier5'))

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='tiers') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TIERS)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    change_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    current = models.BooleanField()
```

*Is tier 1 active on project 1?*

```
project1.tiers.filter(name='TI1', active=True, current=True).exists()
```

*Set tier 3 to active on project 2.*

```
# For simplicity, assume a current state exists. Also, wrap this in a transaction.
current_t3 = project2.tiers.get(name='TI3', current=True)
current_t3.current = False
current_t3.save()
project2.tiers.create(name='TI3', active=True, current=True)
```

*Has project 1 ever used tier 5?*

```
project1.tiers.filter(name='TI5', active=True).exists()
```

*How long has project 2 been using tier 4?*

```
# For simplicity we'll just assume it's active
datetime.now() - project2.tiers.get(name='TI4, current=True).change_time
```

*What projects are currently using tier 3?*

```
Project.objects.filter(tiers__name='TI3', tiers__active=True, tiers__current=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond and type all that out.  
This TiersState model would take the place of both the Tiers and TiersHistory models I have in my initial question, correct?  
Just to make sure I'm getting this, here's a scenario:  
Project 1 currently has  tier 1 active, tier 2 active, and in the past had had tier 5 active 4 times, but was currently inactive.  
I'd have an entry for each of those times the tier became active, a total of 6 entries? (ie, There would be no entries for tier 3 and tier 4 in TierState for project 1)

Comment: @yubus: Yes, there would just be these two models. If you had any data for a tier other than its label, you would want to break that out into its own table. As for your scenario, since you are recording state *changes* you would have 10 `TierHistory` entries: tier 1 (on), tier 2 (on), and tier 5 (on, off, on, off, on, off, on, off). And to make life easier, when you create a new `Project` you'll probably want to create a starting `TierHistory` (off) entry for each tier. That way you don't have to complicate the logic by seeing if an entry already exists.

Answer (score 0):

**I need to keep track of what tiers are active on a particular project**

To do so add a ManyToManyField to your Project Model.  By doing so since you can only select one choice at a time, then when you call the Project object and the tier of that object, you will get the current active tier:

```
class Project(models.Model):
  tier = models.ManyToManyField(Tier)
  # other fields in your Project Model
```

**I need to be able to associate a charge date for the project with active tiers.**

This needs to be a separate transaction table.  So you would want a table with these fields:

```
Charge Date, ProjectID (PK of your Project Model - unique identifier), Active Tier at the time.
```

When a Charge occurs, write to this table to record the transaction.

**UPDATE**

I would advise then making each Tier a Boolean Field.  That way they can be turned on and off as you please.  And you can have multiple tiers on at a time.

To know which tier changed when, you can put that in a transaction table a previously recommended. Create a class method under `Project` to handle this for you.  Or just query the data in you database.

Comment: I added an edit to my initial question to try and clarify the problem. I need a charge date for each tier for each project and each project could have up to all 5 tiers active, or just one active.

I think a transaction table might work to keep the charge date for each tier and project